# SharePoint in Silverlight issue

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

There is a circle on SharePoint2010 page http://sharepoint2010.microsoft.com/Pages/default.aspx which is made by Silverlight. I want to know how to make a Cicle like that with some different parts.

Best Regards,

Comment: http://sharepoint2010.microsoft.com/XAPS/SP2010Hero.xap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just set of six custom control (it can be a user control also) with Path as a main part, and MouseHover event for highlight sector.

Try to look into it with Reflector, its very easy and usefull.

EDIT:
So, I'm looked it with reflector myself. And it's so easy. The pie is just the set of seven .png files. They showed on MouseEnter event of Path controls, one for every six Path, and seventh .png showed when no one Path Fire event. It's just set of pictures.

Comment: Where do you find the XAP file for that site?

Comment: @YongweiXing Fiddler rocks! http://sharepoint2010.microsoft.com/XAPS/SP2010Hero.xap